# UUID type for NEWID()

Tags: sql-server

Does the `NEWID()` function generate `UUID version 4`?

[Link to Wikipedia with versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

What is the situation with the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` function?

Does the data always provide us with the UUID standard and version? Maybe it should be generated on the application side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following to the Wikipedia page that you mentioned above (in the Database key section):

*The `NEWID` function in Microsoft SQL Server version 4 Transact-SQL returns standard random version-4 UUIDs, while the `NEWSEQUENTIALID` function returns 128-bit identifiers similar to UUIDs which are committed to ascend in sequence until the next system reboot.*